# Pipe string to Powershell Generic.List in place of Out-File

Tags: powershell

I have multiple scripts that write custom log lines to a TXT file via `Out-File` like so:

```
$log_txt = 'c:\logging.txt'

#do stuff

"Message 1" | Out-File $log_txt -Append

#do more stuff

"Message 2" | Out-File $log_txt -Append
```

I want to change the structure to write the log messages to a Generic.List `New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]` using `.Add()` method before writing to a txt file at the very end.

However, it would be much easier to modify my scripts if I could simply replace the `Out-File $log_txt -append` with a command to add to the list via Pipeline.

What I would like:

```
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$log_txt = 'c:\logging.txt'

"Message 1" | {function/method/command to add to list}
"Message 2" | {function/method/command to add to list}

$list | out-file $log_txt -append
```

For what I know so far, I would have to wrap each message in `$List.Add()`, like so:

```
$List.Add("Message 1")
$List.Add("Message 2")
```

Which requires more modification than I'd like, both in making the change as well as undoing, if necessary.

Is there another option?

Comment: Another option is `$list += "Message 1"`

Comment: @derloopkat that converts the list into an array so its not really an option unless you dont care about performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [simple `function` or `filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.4) (a function with implied `process` block) to add to your list:

```bash
filter AddToList { $list.Add($_) }
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
'hi' | AddToList
$list
```

With a function you just add the [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.4#process):

```
function AddToList { process { $list.Add($_) } }
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
'hi' | AddToList
$list
```

Comment: Are there any inherent benefits to using one or the other (filter vs function)? I'm not as familiar with `filter`

Comment: it this case not really @sleven

Comment: I'll go with using function as I'm more familiar with it. Thank you, very simple and elegant solution and it works perfectly after some testing.

Comment: @sleven happy to help and yes it makes sense to use `function` really as its more well known. `filter` is just a concise `function` with a `process` block